# concurrencia hilos java

Tags: java, hilos

Estoy tocando el tema de hilos en java y estoy realizando algunas comprobaciones. Quiero extraer e introducir las letras en el array tuberia de dos en dos de forma concurrente y que cada vez que entren o salgan letras me indique las que salen y cuántas quedan en el array tubería.

El código que tengo es este:

```
class ProductorConsumidorTuberia {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Tuberia t = new Tuberia();          // creación de la tubería
        Productor p = new Productor(t);     // creación del productor, recibe la tubería como parámetro
        Consumidor c = new Consumidor(t);   // creación del consumidor, recibe la tubería como parámetro

        p.start();      // se lanza el hilo productor
        c.start();      // se lanza el hilo consumidor
    }
}


class Productor extends Thread {

    private Tuberia tuberia;
    private String alfabeto = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    public Productor(Tuberia t) {           // constructor

            // Mantiene una copia propia del objeto compartido t
            tuberia = t;

    }

    public void run() {

        char c; // almacenará una letra individual


        // Mete 10 letras en la tubería
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

            c = alfabeto.charAt((int) (Math.random() * 26)); // letra del alfabeto al azar

            tuberia.introducir(c);

// Imprime un registro con lo añadido

            System.out.println("Introducida la letra " + c + " a la tuberia.");

// Espera un poco antes de añadir más letras

            try {
                    sleep((int) (Math.random() * 100));

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}


class Consumidor extends Thread {

    private Tuberia tuberia;

    public Consumidor(Tuberia t) {

        tuberia = t;        // Mantiene una copia propia del objeto compartido

    }

    public void run() {

        char c;

// Consume 10 letras de la tubería

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
        {

            c = tuberia.recuperar();  // recupera una letra desde la tubería a través del método sincronizado RECUPERAR

            // Imprime la letra recuperada
            System.out.println("Recuperada la letra " + c);

            // Espera un poco antes de seguir cogiendo más letras (al azar, como máximo 2000ms )
            try {
                        sleep((int) (Math.random() * 2000));

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

}

class Tuberia {

    private char buffer[] = new char[6];

    private int siguiente = 0;

    // banderas para saber el estado del buffer
    private boolean estaLlena = false;
    private boolean estaVacia = true;

    // Método SINCRONIZADO para retirar letras del buffer
    public synchronized char recuperar() {

        // IMPORTANTE: NO se puede consumir si el buffer está vacío
        while (estaVacia == true) {

            try {
                    wait(); // Se sale cuando estaVacia cambia a false

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        }

        // Decrementa la cuenta, ya que va a consumir una letra

        siguiente--;

        // Comprueba si se retiró la última letra

        if (siguiente == 0)     estaVacia = true;

        // El buffer no puede estar lleno, porque acabamos de consumir
        estaLlena = false;

        notify();  //se notifica al monitor de sincronización para ejecute el siguiente hilo en espera (que esté en WAIT), productor o consumidor


        // Devuelve la letra al thread consumidor
        return (buffer[siguiente]);
    }


    // Método SINCRONIZADO para meter letras por la tubería
    public synchronized void introducir(char c) {

        // Espera hasta que haya sitio para otra letra

        while (estaLlena == true) {

            try {
                    wait(); // Se sale cuando estaLlena cambia a false

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        }

        // Añade una letra en el primer lugar disponible
        buffer[siguiente] = c;

        // Cambia al siguiente lugar disponible
        siguiente++;

        // Comprueba si el buffer está lleno
        if (siguiente == 6)     estaLlena = true;

        estaVacia = false; // no puede estar vacía porque se acaba de meter una letra

        notify();  //se notifica al monitor de sincronización para ejecute el siguiente hilo en espera (que esté en WAIT), productor o consumidor

    }

}
```

Comment: Que problema tienes? Que pruebas has hecho? Que esperas conseguir? Que has conseguido?

Comment: He conseguido que me coja las letras y las vaya introduciendo en la tubería mediante el método synchronized hasta que se quede vacío la tubería de letras. He hecho probaturas con el método Arrays.toString ( ___ ) para que me muestre el número de letras que salen y quedan en la tubería. Me falta sacar e introducir dos letras de forma concurrente, hasta ahora solo lo he podido hacer una por una.

Comment: Te sugiero agregar esa información en la pregunta, pues sin leer los comentarios no queda claro que no está haciéndolo de dos en dos.

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo he hecho y no he tenido ningún problema.

Para poder identificar quien produce y quien consume, he introducido ligeros cambios en el código (básicamente dar atributos como nombre a el consumidor y poder crear el alfabeto a través del constructor para el caso del productor).

Este es el código de la clase que lanza los productores y consumidores:

```
public class ProductorConsumidorTuberia {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // creación de la tubería
        Tuberia t = new Tuberia(); 

        // creación del productor, recibe la tubería como parámetro
        Productor p = new Productor(t,"p","ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
        // creación del productor2, recibe la tubería como parámetro
        Productor p2 = new Productor(t,"p2","1234567890");    

        // creación del consumidor, recibe la tubería como parámetro    
        Consumidor c = new Consumidor(t,"c");
        // creación del consumidor 2, recibe la tubería como parámetro      
        Consumidor c2 = new Consumidor(t,"c2");   

        p.start();      // se lanza el hilo productor
        p2.start();      // se lanza el hilo productor2
        c.start();      // se lanza el hilo consumidor
        c2.start();      // se lanza el hilo consumidor2
    }

}
```

Para poder visualizar el conteido de la tuberia simplemente implementa el método toString de la clase Tuberia y ejecútalo, por ejemplo, cada vez que se introduzca un caracter en el buffer.

El método toString es muy simple:

```
public String toString() {
    return "Tuberia buffer=" + Arrays.toString(buffer);
}
```

Saludos.

Comment: Lo que no consigo es como poner el método Array.toString() para que me aparezca en cada momento que salga alguna letra las que quedan en la tuberia.

Comment: Por lo que veo, la clase tuberia guarda su contenido en una array de caracteres (char buffer[]). Simplemente implementa el método toString de la clase.

Comment: Supoongo que te dejaste la `s` en Array.toString()